# Obfuscation of .NET exe/dll

Tags: c#, .net, .net-reflector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET obfuscation of a DLL: how can I protect my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420185/net-obfuscation-of-a-dll-how-can-i-protect-my-code)

Hi all,

I'm using .net framework 4.0 and making any program. When i finished it, i publish it and get my programs exe.
But any 3rd party softwares decompiles my exe and anybody views my codes. 
For example : [image]

How do i save my code?

Thanks all...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use an obfuscation tool, like [Dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator) or [Eazfuscator.NET](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net).

Eazfuscator.NET is free, Dotfuscator has a limited Community Edition, but is lacking many of the features available for free in the other product.

**UPDATE**

Eazfuscator.NET is now commercial.  [This link](http://favsoft.blogspot.ie/2012/08/eazfuscator-net-gone-commercial.html) provides a download link for the last free version and lists some alternatives (as of September 2012)

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. I downloaded Eazfuscator.NET