# Can we make a Visual Studio Solution to have expiration date

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a ***asp.net web project***, and i want to make the solution file to work only for some duration. I have implemented the expiration check on my Dal layer's constructor so that the it will not create the instance of my Entity EDMX (as i am giving only dll to the user so that it will not able to alter the check).

> But I want that my solution will not open in Visual Studio if the
>   specific date is passed.

Comment: I highly doubt this is a feature. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I don't see why you would want that. If you are working in team and trying to restrict people to access the source after a certain duration, remove their access from whatever source control you are using.

Comment: @TimothyShields i want to give my solution to user for only limited time.

Comment: *giving only dll*, there are other ways to manipulate and [get it changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304086/obfuscation-of-net-exe-dll)

Comment: Solution and project files are plain text. Even if you could do this somehow, developers could still access all the data and, presumably, override your expiration date.

Comment: @JonathanWood then what is the alternatives...

Comment: @RazoR: If you want to distribute an executable this way, then just compile it. Of course, skilled enough developers will *still* be able to work around the expiration. But there's no way to prevent use of plain text. If Visual Studio wouldn't load it, they could always just load it in NotePad and fix the expiration. I don't think you can send someone plain text source code and expect them to only be able to use it for a limited time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be looking to other means for this.... Digital Rights Management, permissions, or something along those lines.

Visual Studio isn't the sort of program to restrict data, it relies on operating system functions to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a time based licensing!

Try to check this, this question has been answered already.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a51405b6-cd23-475e-afe6-0b9c3ff2a0e8/c-application-for-time-based-licensing?forum=csharpgeneral